# Headless SSH on Raspberry Pi3B: connection refused

Tags: windows, ssh, putty, raspberry-pi3

Thanks for taking the time and helping me out.

The Aim:

Heedlessly ssh into a Raspberry Pi 3B on my Win7 platform(s).

The problem:

I have two Raspberry Pi 2 B's that I have set up in the past with no issues incl headless setup. I have a new Raspberry Pi 3B and cannot ssh into it at all. I have followed the exact same steps I have for my Pi 2B's with exception to the image.

What I have done so far:

1. Download the latest Raspbian Jessie Image and format the Sd card using Win32DiskImager.
2. Power up the Raspberry
3. Ping the raspberry successfully using the Pi's IP address.
4. Open Putty and enter the IP on port 22 (not that the port should matter)
5. At this point when I try click "Open" after having entered the Pi's IP address I get the following error: "Connection Refused"
6. I then used a Screen and keyboard to boot the Pi 3B. Once booted I opened terminal and entered "sudo raspi-config", where I then enabled SSH manually.
7. I unplugged everything from the Pi3, plugged the LAN cable back into my laptop and Pi3 and powered up the Pi3B.
8. I could still ping the Pi
9. Using Putty and the Pi3B's IP address I then clicked "open" and the following error came up: "Network Error: Software cause connection abort"

EDIT:

I have now also added a router to the setup, checked up what the ip of the pi is through the router and tried connecting with putty onto the pi, but I still get "Network Error: Connection Refused"

I am running out of ideas, any help would be appreciated. 
Thank you
Misha

Comment: Do you have `ssh` on `localhost` (from Pi3 console to localhost)?

Comment: Hi. Excuse the noobness, I am not entirely sure what you mean. On a side note, WIth my exact same setup I have right now on my Win7 laptop, I am able to log into my Pi2B's.

Comment: Open console on Pi3 (from X desktop), then enter `ssh user@localhost`. You will test whether `ssh` daemon is ok and only remote access is the problem or there is no ssh.

Comment: Hi. Thank for your reply! I did what you suggested and it returned "Connection closed by UNKNOWN" when the lan cable was both connected and not connected

Comment: You can test also `telnet 127.0.0.1 22`. If connection is refused, it seems you have no running ssd daemon.

Comment: it seems like i dont. but I dont understand. Why does the brnd new Jessie with PIXEL image not have it? Either way, do you know how this is fixed?

Comment: Maybe this: https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=28&t=142166

Comment: also, another strange thing. On the raspberry pi 2B's, I added a static ip to the cmdline.txt by adding the following to the end of the single line: "ip=192.168.XXX.XXX". When I do this I am able to ping the Pi3B by its ip i gave it. but when i do: "ping raspberrypi", it gives me a different ip address....?

Comment: see `/etc/hosts` and `/etc/hostname` files. maybe the hostname of Pi3 is not "raspberrypi".

Comment: i checked the hostname files, and the hostname of the pi ist "raspberrypi"

Comment: what I dont get, all the forums say that the they way to ssh into the pi has never changed. And I havent changed anything except for formatting the latest version of Jessie onto an SD card. It should just work right? Could it be that the latest 11-01-2017 version of Jessie does not have ssh turned on as a default? But even then I turned it on manually and it still gave me issues

Answer (score 12, accepted):

After comically large amounts of googling and hassle I found a solution here: https://www.raspberrypi.org/blog/a-security-update-for-raspbian-pixel/

With the RPi3B and 11-01-2017 Raspbian Jessie combo (I dont know with which one the issue lies) one has to add a blank file named "ssh" into the boot directory of the SD card. This can be done on your Windows platform. Ensure that the file has no file extensions, because if it has any file extensions it wont work. Good practice anyway to have your file extensions showing in any case.

Hope this helps anyone else.

Comment: Note this appears to be necessary *even if you have already enabled SSH*. I lost a couple of hours this morning being refused access to a Pi I've been accessing for weeks. Worked perfectly when plugged into monitor/keyboard, refused when not. `ssh` file fixed it. Bewildering.

Comment: Thank you.  This saved me potential hours of headache.

Answer (score 0):

> I have followed the exact same steps I have for my Pi 2B's...

What you didn't do is read the release notes of all the raspbian versions between your old and new image before following those steps. In one of them it says that you have to put a file (can be empty) with name ssh in the boot **partition**. Upon first boot ssh will be enabled and the file removed.

(Don't do what I did. I put the file 'ssh' in the boot *directory* of the main partition, but that turned out to be the mount point for the (small) boot *partition*, hiding the file 'ssh' at mount and rendering the whole exercise without effect. It took me some time before I found my mistake. You have to put the file in the small boot *partition* itself.)

Answer (score 0):

here is what you do 
go to Network & Sharing center & click on the Ethernet connection to Raspberry Pi then IPv4 & set everything to automatically(obtaining IP & DNS server)
then go to details of the Ethernet & check the autoconfiguration IPv4 & note that down.

remove sd card from Ra-Pi and mount to laptop, go to the the boot folder & open the cmdline.txt file, & add after root wait "ip=(autoconfiguration IPv4 + 1 on the last digit)" & save.

this worked for me